# Null values keep showing in Excel even when it is removed in SQL (redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I tried everything possible, but column X needs to show only 'NOT/UNKNOWN' values. It shows even the nulls in excel for that column. Need assistance on how to remove the nulls.

```
select * from a
where  x='NOT/UNKNOWN' and NULLIF(x,'') IS NOT NULL and x<>'' and len(x)>0
```

Comment: Can you share a subset of the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the row where x is 'NOT/UNKNOWN', then the query should simply be as follows.  This will not return rows where x is any other value or NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE x = 'NOT/UNKNOWN'
```